# How [1,2] + [4,5,6][1] = 1,25 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, concatenation

I got this question from Interview,

```
[1,2] + [4,5,6][1]
```

JavaScript giving answer **1,25**.

How it's happening? Please explain clearly.

Comment: [1,2] + [4,5,6][1] = [1,2] + 5 = "1,2" + 5 = "1,25"

Comment: it's a damn good question. Too bad it wouldn't get good exposure due to the uniqueness of the title

Comment: @vsync any suggestion for title?

Comment: @vsync: There are dozens if not hundreds of these obscure type coercive questions. Simple answer is always the same... JS operators work on all values. Values that don't make sense are usually coerced to some other value. Referencing the ECMAScript spec is a crucial step that many people skip.

Comment: So, you are actual question seems to be why `[4,5,6][1]` returns `5`. That's because you are accessing the second element of the array. That's not really surprising I hope.

Comment: who says it "opinion-based" ??!!!

Comment: @FelixKling - actually that is the easiest part of this "riddle". It is the illogical part of type-casting the left side of the operator which is non-trivial

Comment: @vsync: I know. But the OP said, before the edit, *"I know `[1,2]+5 => 1,25`. Here **[4,5,6][1] => 5 ?**"*. So I assumed they know what happens to the first operand.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Lets start with the last part and write it more verbose

```
var arr   = [4,5,6];
var value = arr[1];
```

Is the same as

```
[4,5,6][1]
```

and as arrays are zero based, that gives `5`, so we really have

```
[1,2] + 5;
```

The first part is equal to

```
[1,2].toString(),
```

and that returns the string `"1,2"` because the array is converted to a string when trying to use it in an expression like that, as arrays can't be added to numbers,  and then we have

```
"1,2" + 5
```

Concatenating strings with numbers gives strings, and adding the strings together we get

```
"1,25"
```

Comment: why would `[1,2]` be represented as a String?

Comment: Because JS coerces the array to something it understands the `+` operator for.

Comment: I had no idea the `+` operator affects things left to it

Comment: @vsync Because you can't represent `[1,2]` as a number

Comment: but why would a language do that? it would be logical to give an error instead of converting the left side to a string. that is just craziness right there

Comment: JavaScript generally tries to convert stuff to other stuff it understands, mostly strings, which is why one can do `"3" + 3` and get `"33"`

Comment: @vsync: Given your experience with JavaScript, I'm surprised you (still) think any of this is crazy.

Comment: @BoltClock - coding in JS for over a decade and still am surprised to discover new things now and then. My specialty in JS does not include instantiates, which I try to avoid.  Anyway, you gave a good answer.

Comment: @vsync: Dynamic typing is one of the core aspects of JS - which is why I was surprised this was new to you. Still, knowing JS, it *always* finds ways to surprise us.

Answer (score 7):

It breaks down like this:

Starting with:

```
[1,2] + [4,5,6][1]
```

First, each side gets evaluated, and since the right-hand side is an array initializer and lookup, it comes out to `5`:

```
[1,2] + 5
```

Now [the `+` operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1) starts its work. It isn't defined for arrays, the first thing it does is try to convert its operands into either strings or numbers. In the case of an array, it'll be a string as though from `Array#toString`, which does `Array#join`, giving us:

```
"1,2" + 5
```

When you use `+` where either side is a string, the result is string concatenation.

Answer (score 2):

First, `[4,5,6][1]` evaluates to the number `5`

Then, the `+` operator is being applied to a first argument which is an `Array` and not a `Number`, so javascript assumes you're doing a string concatenation, not addition. Your array `[1,2]` becomes a string, which is `"1,2"`. You can see this yourself with `[1,2].toString()`.

The number `5` is now being appended to a string, so it to gets converted to a string, and appended together to get `"1,25"`.