# Why console.log([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10][1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7][1, 2, 3]) logs undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have followed these links

[How [1,2] + [4,5,6][1] = 1,25 in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29867933/how-1-2-4-5-61-1-25-in-javascript?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Why does [5,6,8,7][1,2] = 8 in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421013/why-does-5-6-8-71-2-8-in-javascript)

but not able to understand why the following code is `undefined`. My understanding is `[1,2,3]` will give 3, so from `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7][3]` will be 4 and hence `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` will be `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10][4]` that is 5. But it logs undefined.

```js
console.log([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10][1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7][1, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right track. The second and third group of `[...]` are a property access with bracket notation, and the `1, 2, 3` are treated as comma operators, evaluating to the last entry in the list. So your code is basically the same as:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10][7][3]
```

Now the seventh number in the array is 8:

```
 8[3]
```

and that does not have a `"3"` property.

Answer (score 1):

Breaking it down into the two steps actually executed may help. First you get an `8`, a number, then you try to index it – `undefined` ahoy!

```
> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10][1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
8
> 8[1,2,3]
undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

You define 1D array `a=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` but you  treat it as 2D array during value reading `a[...][...]` (the `a[...]` returns array element - which is number - not array). This is the mistake in idea behind your code.

```js
a=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
console.log( a[0][0] );
```